# Rails Serializer - Access grandparent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given this example:

```
class School
  has_many :teachers
end
```

```
class Teacher
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :students
end
```

```
class Student
  belongs_to :teacher
  delegate :school, to: :teacher, allow_nil: true
end
```

I can easily access School with `Student.first.school` but how can I do it with `JSONAPI::Serializer`?

Is it possible to have a Serializer where `student.school` is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Just use an indirect assocation instead of delegation:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :teacher
  has_one :school, through: :teacher
end

class StudentSerializer 
  include JSONAPI::Serializer
  has_one :school
end
```